# How to simulate Google maps Marker inheritance on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, inheritance, marker

I would like to simulate an inheritance of Marker from Google Maps API V2. I know it's impossible to inherit from Marker because Marker is a final class and that's my problem.

My final goal: create a Marker (let's call this one MainPoint) which deploys 5 others Marker (let's call them Petal) when I click on it and hides them when I click again.

When Petals are deployed around MainPoint, thanks to onMarkerClickListener I can catch the marker but I can't identify if this marker is a MainPoint or a Petal.

If I could make Petal and MainPoint inherit from Marker or even put a tag on it, I would just have to check if this is a Petal or a MainPoint to know which method I have to call but with only the instance of a Marker, the only way I found is to check every instance of every MainPoint and its Petals if it's equal to the marker clicked.

I hope you can help me to find a way to design this situation.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't identify if this marker is a MainPoint or a Petal

Maintain a `HashMap` mapping petal `Marker` IDs to main point `Marker` IDs. Look up your `Marker` in the `HashMap` to find its associated main point, and if you get back `null`, you know that it *is* a main point.